# WeakReference as method argument

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, reference, garbage-collection

I have a question about `WeakReference`.

I have WPF App as TCP client and use `WeakReference` to pass window instance to "client logic" (To avoid memory leaks if window will close while request running) . 
I have a window and 2 method realisations (1) and (2):

```
//Window
public partial class MainWindow : Window, IAnswerListener 
{
    //code here
    private void On_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //(2) // Request(new WeakReference<IAnswerListener>(this))
        // or 
        //(1) // Request(this)
    }
}

//class with logic
//Request method (1)
public void Request(IAnswerListener listener) 
{
    var weakRef = new WeakReference<IAnswerListener>(listener);
    NextCall(weakRef);
}

//Request method (2)
public void Request(WeakReference<IAnswerListener> listener)
{
    NextCall(listener); 
}
```

Which type of request better to use ? Will left reference  in type (1) case if window was closed or reference free by GC ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, you can use whichever option you like more. I prefer first.

Comment: First point. No leaks, worst case you will work with a closed (but not disposed) window. This introduces the second point: closing a window doesn't dispose it (and it may become eligible for collection after request finishes). Third point is more practical, in wpf you shouldn't work with UI controls but with View Model (and this will also nicely solve all your issues about lifetime)

Comment: Binding uses weak references. Why would you not use binding and present a viewmodel to the window or create a viewmodel as a private member of the window ( so it  then goes away when the window does) and use pub sub if you need to receive external messaging.